# django saving two model in a one to many relationship

Tags: django

I trying to save two model in a one to many relationships but I am getting the error NOT NULL constraint failed:domestic_banks_naturalperson.domesticbank_id

model

```html
# Create your models here
class DomesticBank(models.Model):
    bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    subsidiary_or_branch = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    home_country = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField('Date Published', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bank_name


class NaturalPerson(models.Model):
    domesticbank = models.ForeignKey(DomesticBank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    natural_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    upload_passport_copy = models.FileField(upload_to='Passport/PDF', null=True)
    upload_additional_ID = models.FileField(upload_to='Other_ID/PDF', null=True)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.natural_person_name
```

```html
def add_bank_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BankForm(request.POST)
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        OwnShares = OwnSharesInOtherCompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid() and natural_person_form.is_valid():
            form = form.save()
            naturalperson = natural_person_form.save(commit=False)
            naturalperson.form = form
            naturalperson.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/DisplayBankRisk')
    else:
        form = BankForm()
        natural_person_form = NaturalPpersonPform()
        
    return render(request, 'add_domestic_bank.html', locals())
```

Comment: It looks like it's because the `domesticbank` field isn't being set. i.e. `naturalperson.form = form` should be `naturalperson.domesticbank = form`

Comment: Thank you that was it. I overlooked that.